# Discrete digital input

Tags: digital-logic

I have a homework question that mentions discrete inputs and I wanted to clear up some of my confusion on the topic. When looking at truth tables, as an example, would A and A' be two discrete inputs?

Comment: Might need some more information. "A" sounds like it could be an input, but "A'" sounds like it could be "A" after some logical operation.

Comment: A' would be the opposite of A

Comment: A' could also be the state of A in the next clock cycle (read "next A"), depending on the context of the question

Comment: Would you mind to [edit] your question and show us the complete sentence that uses the term? You could also add a summary of the relevant part of your lecture's script concerning (discrete) inputs.